# How do I set default value of md-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using @angular/material@latest ,
but the doc didn't say how can I set the default option of md-select.
I tried selected attribution but didn't work;

```
<md-select>
<md-option selected value="a">a</md-option>
<md-option selected value="b">b</md-option>
<md-select>
```

Comment: use `[(ngModel)]` on `md-select`. BTW, do not set `selected` on multiple `md-option`, single option with `selected` will also work.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Just confirmed that `selected` fits for basic `select`, not fit for `md-select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an  **`[(ngModel)]="selectedopt"`**

```
<md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedopt">
```

and set in TS;

```
 selectedopt = "a";
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ht28EzzSNxxgWMRJdNa?p=preview)**

Comment: OP is using **@angular/material** which is for **angular2+**, please confirm before answer.

Comment: @Pengyy Yeah right! updated ! thanks for the headsup

Comment: It is worth noting that `selectedopt` should be the same as the `[value]` attributes in the `<md-option/>` markup. It took me a few minutes to figure why the default value didn't work..